# Como correr todos os ficheiros dentro de um folder

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Tenho uma pasta com vários ficheiros de áudio e quero que o código cmd corra todos, um de cada vez. Alguém tem ideia se isto é possível e se sim, como se faz?

Comment: João, para os companheiros brasileiros, o que seria correr ?

Comment: Por correr quero dizer run/executar. Neste caso refiro-me à reprodução dos ficheiros áudio.

Comment: Já que você está utilizando VLC, criar uma playlist a partir de um diretório resolve seu problema?

Comment: Como faço para criar uma playlist com o batch?

Comment: Recomendo [edit] sua pergunta para deixá-la mais específica, incluindo detalhes que você forneceu via comentários (usando VLC, suas tentativas anteriores)

Answer (score 1):

Retirando do SO en [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

acho que seria algo tipo isso:

```
FOR %x IN (*.mp3) DO call player-mp3.exe "%x"
```

onde você teria que ter na mesma pasta um player-mp3.exe, que toque a musica passada como parâmetro.

mas não sei se o `for` vai esperar uma musica terminar para iniciar a próxima, creio que ele execute tudo ao mesmo tempo

Comment: `for /r "path" %%f in (*.mp3) do start /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN" "%%f"`
Dá para executar com outro programa. Neste caso estou a reproduzir com o VLC. O código que escreveu é o mesmo que eu tenho e, de facto, o problema é ele não fazer a iteração. Ou seja, apenas reproduz o primeiro e ignora os restantes.

Comment: tente passar uma playlist como parâmetro, sem o uso do for...

Comment: Jader, obrigado pela sugestão. Talvez possa ser desenvolvida em conjunto em cima em resposta ao gmsantos?

Answer (score 1):

Crie um batch com o seguinte conteúdo (Supondo que você esteja utilizando a versão 32 bits):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --playlist-autostart --loop --fullscreen --playlist-tree %1
```

Modo de uso:

```
> cria_playlist.bat c:\path\para\as\minhas\musicas
```

Comment: Aplicando esse código, o VLC abre e depois consigo a seguinte mensagem no cmd window
_'cria_playlist.bat' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, programa operacional ou ficheiro batch_

Comment: Precisa salvar o arquivo e navegar ate a pasta dele, ou salvar no path do sistema

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso e pus o path correcto. A mensagem de que falei, foi já com esse path.

Comment: @JoãoPontes em casa tenho o VLC, irei testar mais tarde.